# How to build listbox's items with different controls in one listbox

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox

In my application i show newsfeed from social network vkontakte (russian facebook:) ). I send request to server and receive an xml file, whitch inludes about 50 newsfeed items. Example of xml (2 items of 50)

```
    <item>
  <type>post</type>
  <source_id>-26406986</source_id>
  <date>1356207001</date>
  <post_id>1058858</post_id>
  <text>#Суть на #lm.</text>
  <attachment>
    <type>photo</type>
    <photo>
      <pid>293678498</pid>
      <aid>-7</aid>
      <owner_id>-26406986</owner_id>
      <user_id>65647811</user_id>
      <src>http://cs406928.userapi.com/v406928811/61c7/Rjee0rUq3vU.jpg</src>
      <src_big>http://cs406928.userapi.com/v406928811/61c8/PSYiLcxlv9s.jpg</src_big>
      <src_small>http://cs406928.userapi.com/v406928811/61c6/26XXAbejR7U.jpg</src_small>
      <width>186</width>
      <height>604</height>
      <text />
      <created>1356203380</created>
      <access_key>ca379f61ca5de866ae</access_key>
    </photo>
  </attachment>
  <attachments list="true">
    <attachment>
      <type>photo</type>
      <photo>
        <pid>293678498</pid>
        <aid>-7</aid>
        <owner_id>-26406986</owner_id>
        <user_id>65647811</user_id>
        <src>http://cs406928.userapi.com/v406928811/61c7/Rjee0rUq3vU.jpg</src>
        <src_big>http://cs406928.userapi.com/v406928811/61c8/PSYiLcxlv9s.jpg</src_big>
        <src_small>http://cs406928.userapi.com/v406928811/61c6/26XXAbejR7U.jpg</src_small>
        <width>186</width>
        <height>604</height>
        <text />
        <created>1356203380</created>
        <access_key>ca379f61ca5de866ae</access_key>
      </photo>
    </attachment>
  </attachments>
  <comments>
    <count>47</count>
    <can_post>1</can_post>
  </comments>
  <likes>
    <count>167</count>
    <user_likes>0</user_likes>
    <can_like>1</can_like>
    <can_publish>1</can_publish>
  </likes>
  <reposts>
    <count>35</count>
    <user_reposted>0</user_reposted>
  </reposts>
  <post_source>
    <type>vk</type>
  </post_source>
</item>
```

each item can have different content in `<attachments>`(text, photo, video, audio, document, text n photo, text n audio, and all possible combinatios of this staff). I already asked this question here. And i had an answer - use template selector. Well... i used it, and now i have 16 different `listbox`'s items, and it's not all possible combinations. Its realy huge code in xaml. Example, 2 templates:

video and audios

```
      <!--VideonAudios-->          <local:NewsTemplateSelector.VideonAudios>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Name="VideoGrid" MaxHeight="2000" Tap="ListBoxTap"   >
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="28"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}" Tap="GetUserInfo"  Width="75"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceName}"   FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Copy_owner_name}"    FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="39,0,0,0" MaxHeight="35"/>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Copy_owner_photo}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Width="39" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Video[0].Title}"    FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="auto" />
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Video[0].Big}" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Tap="Video_Tap"  />
                                        <ListBox Name="audiosListbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Audio}"  MaxHeight="500" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" >
                                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1"   FontSize="25" Tap="AudioTitleTap" />
                                                        <Button Content="Play"  Height="70" Tap="Audios_Button_Click" />
                                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Count}" Tag="Count" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ListBox>
                                        <Image Source="\icons\appbar.check.rest.png" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="4" Width="30" Margin="0,1.5,34,-1.5" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalMargin"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="4"  />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Likes}" Name="LikeTxtBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="4"   TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="30" Margin="0,0.5,0,-0.5"/>
                                        <Line X1="0" Y1="27" X2="420" Y2="27" Margin="0,-28,0,0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="1"  />
                                        <Line X1="0" Y1="27" X2="80" Y2="27" Margin="0,-28,0,0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" />
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Video[0].Url}" Tag="VURL" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:NewsTemplateSelector.VideonAudios>
```

And its only 2 templates from 16. Well... it works. 
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

But, sometimes listbox starts work with some strange behavior, i think its because of this templates. And now, i have to make similar listbox on different page, and i think its not good idea to use template selector. Can anyone tell me, is there any different ways to build `listbox`s item with different content?

UPD: the way i parse xml

```
 void c_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      //  string str = null;
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(e.Result); //полученый xml от апи вконтакта
        MessageBox.Show(xml.ToString());
        var inf = from c in xml.Descendants("item") // 
                  select c;
        int j = -1;
        int i = 0;
        App.New_From = (string)xml.Element("response").Element("new_from").Value;
        foreach (var item in inf)
        {
            #region static info
            i++;
            if (inf.Count() > i)
            {
                if ((string)item.Element("type").Value != "friend")
                {
                    New new1 = new New();
                    if ((string)item.Element("source_id").Value != null)
                    {
                        new1.SourseId = (string)item.Element("source_id").Value;
                    }
                    if ((string)item.Element("date").Value != null)
                    {
                       // MessageBox.Show(item.Element("date").Value);
                        new1.Time = App.GetTime(item.Element("date").Value);
                      //  MessageBox.Show(App.GetTime(item.Element("date").Value));
                    }
                    if (item.Element("photos") != null)
                    {
                        var photos = from c in item.Descendants("photo") // 
                                     select c;
                        foreach (var ph in photos)
                        {
                            PhotoAttachment photo = new PhotoAttachment();
                            photo.OwnerId = ph.Element("owner_id").Value;
                            photo.PId = ph.Element("pid").Value;
                            photo.Small = ph.Element("src_small").Value;
                            photo.Big = ph.Element("src_big").Value;
                            if (ph.Element("src_xxbig") != null)
                                photo.xBig = ph.Element("src_xxbig").Value;
                            else if (ph.Element("src_xbig") != null)
                                photo.xBig = ph.Element("src_xbig").Value;
                            else
                                photo.xBig = ph.Element("src_big").Value;
                            new1.photoAttachments.Add(photo);
                        }
                    }
                    if (item.Element("copy_owner_id") != null)
                    {
                        new1.Copy_owner_id = (string)item.Element("copy_owner_id").Value;
                    }
                    if (item.Element("post_id") != null)
                    {
                        new1.Post_id = (string)item.Element("post_id").Value;
                    }
                    if ((string)item.Element("text") != null)
                    {
                        new1.Texts = (string)item.Element("text");
                    }
                    if ((string)item.Element("comment") != null)
                        new1.Comments = (string)item.Element("comment").Element("count").Value;
                    if ((string)item.Element("likes") != null)
                        new1.Likes = (string)item.Element("likes").Element("count").Value;
            #endregion
                    if (item.Element("attachment") != null)
                    {
                        var vd = from c in item.Descendants("attachment")
                                 select c;
                        foreach (var content in vd)
                        {

                            if (content.Element("audio") != null)
                            {
                                AudioAttachment audio = new AudioAttachment();
                                audio.Title = (string)content.Element("audio").Element("title").Value;
                                audio.Perfomer = (string)content.Element("audio").Element("performer").Value;
                                string tmp = audio.Perfomer + " - " + audio.Title;
                                audio.Title = tmp;
                                audio.OwnerId = (string)content.Element("audio").Element("owner_id").Value;
                                audio.Audio_Id = (string)content.Element("audio").Element("aid").Value;
                                audio.Duration = (string)content.Element("audio").Element("duration").Value;
                                audio.Url = audio.OwnerId + "_" + audio.Audio_Id;
                                audio.Count = j++;
                                if (new1.audioAttachments.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    if (audio.Audio_Id == new1.audioAttachments[0].Audio_Id)
                                    {
                                        new1.audioAttachments.RemoveAt(0);
                                    }
                                }
                                new1.audioAttachments.Add(audio);
                            }
                            if (content.Element("photo") != null)
                            {
                                PhotoAttachment photo = new PhotoAttachment();
                                photo.OwnerId = (string)content.Element("photo").Element("owner_id").Value;
                                photo.PId = (string)content.Element("photo").Element("pid").Value;
                                photo.Small = (string)content.Element("photo").Element("src_small").Value;
                                photo.Big = (string)content.Element("photo").Element("src_big").Value;
                                if (content.Element("photo").Element("src_xxbig") != null)
                                    photo.xBig = (string)content.Element("photo").Element("src_xxbig").Value;
                                else if (content.Element("photo").Element("src_xbig") != null)
                                    photo.xBig = (string)content.Element("photo").Element("src_xbig").Value;
                                else
                                    photo.xBig = (string)content.Element("photo").Element("src_big").Value;
                                if (new1.photoAttachments.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    if (photo.Big == new1.photoAttachments[0].Big)
                                    {
                                        new1.photoAttachments.RemoveAt(0);
                                    }
                                }
                                new1.photoAttachments.Add(photo);
                            }

                            if (content.Element("video") != null)
                            {
                                VideoAttachment video = new VideoAttachment();
                                video.Title = (string)content.Element("video").Element("title").Value;
                                video.Description = (string)content.Element("video").Element("description").Value;
                                video.OwnerId = (string)content.Element("video").Element("owner_id").Value;
                                if ((string)content.Element("video").Element("image_small") != null)
                                    video.Small = (string)content.Element("video").Element("image_small").Value;
                                if ((string)content.Element("video").Element("image_big") != null)
                                    video.Big = (string)content.Element("video").Element("image_big").Value;
                                video.Video_Id = (string)content.Element("video").Element("vid").Value;
                                video.Url = video.OwnerId + "_" + video.Video_Id;
                                if (new1.videoAttachments.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    if (video.Big == new1.videoAttachments[0].Big)
                                    {
                                        new1.videoAttachments.RemoveAt(0);
                                    }

                                }
                                new1.videoAttachments.Add(video);
                            }

                            if (content.Element("link") != null)
                            {
                                new1.Priority = PostType.Link;
                                new1.Url.Title = (string)content.Element("link").Element("title").Value;
                                new1.Url.Description = (string)content.Element("link").Element("description").Value;
                                new1.Url.Url = (string)content.Element("link").Element("url").Value;
                                if ((string)content.Element("link").Element("image_src") != null)
                                    new1.Url.Image = (string)content.Element("link").Element("image_src").Value;
                                else if (new1.photoAttachments.Count > 0 && new1.photoAttachments[0].Big != null)
                                    new1.Url.Image = new1.photoAttachments[0].Big;
                                else if (new1.photoAttachments.Count > 0 && new1.photoAttachments[1].Big != null)
                                    new1.Url.Image = new1.photoAttachments[1].Big;

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (item.Element("comments") != null)
                    {
                        if (item.Element("comments").Element("can_post") != null)
                            new1.CanPost = Convert.ToInt32(item.Element("comments").Element("can_post").Value);
                    }


                    //str += string.Format("{0} {1} {2}\n", NewsList.Count, new1.audioAttachments.Count, new1.photoAttachments.Count);

                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.videoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.audioAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.Text;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count == 1 && new1.videoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.audioAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.Photo;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count > 1 && new1.videoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.audioAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.Photos;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.videoAttachments.Count == 1 && new1.audioAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.Video;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.videoAttachments.Count > 1 && new1.audioAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.Videos;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.videoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.audioAttachments.Count == 1 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.Audio;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.videoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.audioAttachments.Count > 1 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.Audios;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count == 1 && new1.videoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.audioAttachments.Count == 1 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.PhotonAudio;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count == 1 && new1.videoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.audioAttachments.Count > 1 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.PhotonAudios;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count > 1 && new1.videoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.audioAttachments.Count == 1 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.PhotosnAudio;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count > 1 && new1.videoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.audioAttachments.Count > 1 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.PhotosnAudios;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.videoAttachments.Count == 1 && new1.audioAttachments.Count == 1 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.VideonAudio;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.videoAttachments.Count == 1 && new1.audioAttachments.Count > 1 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.VideonAudios;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.videoAttachments.Count > 1 && new1.audioAttachments.Count == 1 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.VideosnAudio;
                    if (new1.photoAttachments.Count == 0 && new1.videoAttachments.Count > 1 && new1.audioAttachments.Count > 1 && new1.urlAttachment.Url == null) new1.Priority = PostType.VideosnAudios;


                    NewsList.Add(new1);
                    new1 = null;
                }
            }
```

can i do something like

```
    <local:NewsTemplateSelector.Content.Audios>
<ListBox Name="audiosListbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Audio}"  MaxHeight="500" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1"   FontSize="25" Tap="AudioTitleTap" />
                <Button Content="Play"  Height="70" Tap="Audios_Button_Click" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Count}" Tag="Count" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
<local:NewsTemplateSelector.Content.Audios>
```

and similar for Image, Video, Videos etc. And then use it like

```
<!--Audios-->
<local:NewsTemplateSelector.Audios>
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Name="AudiosGrid" MaxHeight="2000" Tap="ListBoxTap"    >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="28"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}" Tap="GetUserInfo"  Width="75"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceName}"   FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Copy_owner_name}"    FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="39,0,0,0" MaxHeight="35"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding Copy_owner_photo}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Width="39" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Texts}"    FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="auto" />
        <local:NewsTemplateSelector.Content.Audios>
        </local:NewsTemplateSelector.Content.Audios>
        <Image Source="\icons\appbar.check.rest.png" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="3" Width="30" Margin="0,1.5,34,-1.5" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalMargin"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3"  />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Likes}" Name="LikeTxtBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="3"   TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="30" Margin="0,0.5,0,-0.5"/>
        <Line X1="0" Y1="27" X2="420" Y2="27" Margin="0,-28,0,0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="1"  />
        <Line X1="0" Y1="27" X2="80" Y2="27" Margin="0,-28,0,0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

not a

```
<!--Audios-->
<local:NewsTemplateSelector.Audios>
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Name="AudiosGrid" MaxHeight="2000" Tap="ListBoxTap"    >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="28"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}" Tap="GetUserInfo"  Width="75"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceName}"   FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Copy_owner_name}"    FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="39,0,0,0" MaxHeight="35"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding Copy_owner_photo}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Width="39" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Texts}"    FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="auto" />
        <ListBox Name="audiosListbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Audio}"  MaxHeight="500" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1"   FontSize="25" Tap="AudioTitleTap" />
                        <Button Content="Play"  Height="70" Tap="Audios_Button_Click" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Count}" Tag="Count" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Image Source="\icons\appbar.check.rest.png" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="3" Width="30" Margin="0,1.5,34,-1.5" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalMargin"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3"  />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Likes}" Name="LikeTxtBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="3"   TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="30" Margin="0,0.5,0,-0.5"/>
        <Line X1="0" Y1="27" X2="420" Y2="27" Margin="0,-28,0,0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="1"  />
        <Line X1="0" Y1="27" X2="80" Y2="27" Margin="0,-28,0,0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Also, I wouldn't categorize the priority of items the way you did in the parser. Instead, you should let the UI logic (such as the template selector) check your object's content and figure out what sort of visual to spit out on the screen depending on each attachment, one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, each XML component with radically different content (such as a video vs an image, or just text, etc) will require a different template. But you should define your templates into a different XAML file and add it to each control as a ressource dictionary. This way, you can define the templates in 1 place and import them in all your controls without having to copy/paste anything. You can even import multiple XAML files this way using `MergedDictionary`.

I'm not sure how you read your XML files from that site, but maybe you should parse them to custom objects in code-behind, in simpler categories? This would give a more streamlined feel to your application as well. Otherwise said, parse the XML in code-behind, identify what sort of content it is and populate your own "Video", "Image" and "Text" objects. If you can categorize many different XML parts into the same object, you'll have to rely on fewer template selectors/datatemplates in the long run.

But of course I'm speculating a lot of things, hopefully this helps you a bit.

EDIT:

1. Instead of supplying "visual" styles manually on each control, define styles in a resource dictionary and put things like default fontsize, alignments, textwrap preferences into it. Then you can use it like this: `Style="{StaticResource=TextCommentStyle}"`.
2. For your video/audio/etc controls, create one container per type of item you need to show. Each different item should get a different UserControl, which acts as the container.
3. Then, you can use a template selector to display just the UserControl you want depending on the  tag of each attachement. I believe each one should be hosted in a separate ListItem.

The advantages of using this approach is that you'll have fewer containers and you'll let the application "compose" them using the template selector. If there's a video and some text, well the datatemplate should put the video in a ListItem and the text in another ListItem, using their respective UserControls. If you need to edit how a video is shown, you just edit 1 video UserControl and it's reflected in the whole application. It's the same idea with styles for the WPF controls: set them in a style and you can change them globally in a single file. It's much more easy to maintain and debug.

Comment: I added the code how i parse xml. I read your comment, and if I understand you in right way, i can create a ressource dictionary, where I define controls "Video","Audio", "Image" and "Text" like i show in "UPD" and then group them to `listbox`'s item

Comment: I updated the description with some clarification. I would use the resource dictionary to hold anything related to the visual styles and also to hold the datatemplates, but I would use one different UserControl per type of attachment or content (including the simplest textbox or comment) you need to handle.